# I need to know age, retail price and manufacturer of my "Flanders Team Relay" road bike

Tags: road-bike

[image]20 speed  Flanders Team Relay road bike w/ Shimano Tiagra derailleur, Daytona Campagnola brakes & Mavic Race rims

Comment: For any particular purpose or just to waste someone else's time?! Really though, you need to supply a photo and maybe mention what you have found out by yourself and what answers are missing. Please rewrite the question with some detail and try again.

Comment: Why do you need to know this information, what problem does knowing this information solve?

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, it can be difficult to get an exact age, but a photo or a good description of the components can help provide an age range. It is usually asking too much to ask people to recall the retail price unless it was something you could find on Google. Without a photo, the task becomes exponentially harder unless significant and helpful detail is supplied in text.

When people say something like "Flanders Team Relay", usually the first word is the manufacturer and the second word or words is the model name. But there doesn't appear to be a manufacturer called Flanders. The word "Team", as Criggie alludes, may sometimes indicate one of the higher-end models (as in, the manufacturer sponsored a professional racing team and gave them that bike).

If you correctly described the components, that can help give an age range. However, you provided potentially contradictory information. You said "20-speed", which means that you have 2 chainrings and 10 cogs on the rear. You mentioned Shimano Tiagra, which is a lower-end Shimano group. Tiagra 4600 was, I believe, the first 10-speed version of that group, and it came out in 2012. You also mentioned Campagnolo Daytona, which was a groupset released around the early 2000s. In the middle 2000s, it was renamed Centaur. Centaur may have gone to 11s in 2010 or so, but my memory here is not reliable. Also, a stock bike wouldn't mix Shimano and Campagnolo. So, someone may have replaced some parts afterwards for whatever reason. Therefore, we don't know how many stock parts are on the bike, and thus it's harder to rely on the groupset to date the bike.

If you are trying to sell aftermarket, knowing the exact year, especially of a lower-end bike, will not help. Bikes don't hold value very well. Also, bikes have evolved, and the standards on your bike will be dated. The exact year and model would be relevant for a bike with heritage value, but those are rare and not many bikes hold that sort of value, and not to many people either. That said, if you just want to know which replacement parts to get, that's better dealt with at a bike store. Replacement parts will generally be available unless it was something really rare, and 10s Tiagra isn't rare. Daytona is more rare, but Campagnolo still makes 10s chains and cassettes.

Mavic is the wheel or rim manufacturer, and for the record, I don't recall hearing of a model called "Race" around this time period. So, that detail is not helpful either.

When people post to forums, do realize that in asking people to identify a bike, you are asking them to do work for you. The only compensation is community recognition. While I recognize that when one knows little about bikes, it's hard to tell which details are important. Thus, you have to provide a photo at minimum, and it has to be a decent photo - obviously we aren't asking for professional quality, but it has to offer enough detail, and it has to be present. If you don't help people do the work you are asking them to do, you very often can't expect an informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its worth as much as someone is prepared to pay for it in your area.  We can't give valuations sorry - that's offtopic.

Tiagra is a weird choice for a groupset - its 10 speed but not the "team racing" models which would be Dura Ace or maybe Ultegra for a training bike.

Posting a clear photo of your bike from the right hand side might help us estimate an age.